# How to run Aiogram webhook with self-signed ssl certificate?

Tags: python, ssl, webhooks, self-signed-certificate, aiogram

I need to install a Telegram bot on linux machine, but I encountered one problem.

As far as I understand, function aiogram.utils.executor.start_webhook launches server that catches POST requests. And this server uses aiohttp under the hood.

How I can make it work with self-signed ssl certificate?
When using pure aiohttp it is possible to specify ssl context. Is this possible for aiogram оr use of web-server like nginx is the only option?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an example of this in the Aiogram documentation, and there is another example in the development documentation. I don't know why the current example (v2.2.2) doesn't have it (perhaps it still works but is buried in the kwargs).

The [old example](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example_2.html) shows an `ssl` import and setting the `WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT` and `WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV` locations, based on the [Telegram bot rules](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed).

The development branch (v3.0.0) has the certificate as a [function parameter](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/set_webhook.html).

It looks like the current process is to have the ssl set in the [initialisation of the BaseBot](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/bot/base.html?highlight=ssl):

```
# aiohttp main session
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
```

This suggests that currently the certificate must be in the certificate store or else you would need to supply a new `ssl_context` to the bot: `self._connector_init = dict(limit=connections_limit, ssl=ssl_context)`

This should point you in the right direction for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so far that providing ssl context is unavailable in current version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in AiohttpSession class object. Change _connector_init and pass it as a session to the bot constructor

```
from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession
session = AiohttpSession()
session._connector_init = {'ssl': False}
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML, session=session)
```